# Import embedded csv file to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv

I am working on some code that creates a new database which I then want to populate with some required data. I have written a method `MySqlCommand` that connects to SQL Server and sends it SQL instructions. I wrote the code below to check that I can import the required data from a `.csv` file on my hard disk and this all works fine:

```
MySqlCommand("BULK " +
             "INSERT Competition " +
             "FROM 'D:\\Users\\Stephen\\Documents\\Competition.csv'" +
             "WITH (" +
             "FIELDTERMINATOR = ','," +
             "ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')");
```

Now I have added the `.csv` file as an embedded resource in my Visual Studio project and I wish to import the data to the database from there. I have figured out that I can access the embedded resource using:

```
var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Competition.csv");
```

I am now stuck though as I do not know how I might allow SQL Server to access the embedded resource data and I suspect I need to approach this differently. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured out a way to do this and thought I would post the answer to help others:

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("BetfairDatabaseMDI.embeddedResources.Competition.csv"))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            string result = reader.ReadLine();
                            result = "'" + result + "'";
                            result = result.Replace(",", "','");

                            MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Competition " +
                                        "VALUES (" + result + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The idea I had was to read the embedded resource line by line and send the instructions to add each line to the SQL table 1 by 1. I guess its not as efficient as a method using bulk insert but its a one off command so not a problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project similar,

what i did was add the items to a data table and gave it strict values.

then  i looped through each row and inserted it,

this took a long time.

The reason i couldnt do a bulk insert was because the csv was on my local machine and the sql server was on another remote place.

If you have sql on your machine, the insert command looks something like this,

```
BULK
INSERT myCSVFile
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```